# Cannot create foreign key in MySQL error: 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I have created the following tables and have no idea why my foreign key constraint script is not working.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`project_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`project_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`cons_bal` int(11) NOT NULL,
`non_cons_bal` int(11) NOT NULL,
`budget_head` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And here is my another table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_map` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`project_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`head` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is my add constraint line:

```
alter table project_map add constraint p_map_fk001 foreign key (`project_id`) references project(`project_id`)
```

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: The docs say: `in the event of a foreign key error involving InnoDB tables (usually Error 150 in the MySQL Server), you can obtain a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error by checking the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS. `

Comment: Maybe it's not a requirement, but it's good practice to have foreign key property in source table as Primary Key

Comment: The result of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

Error in foreign key constraint of table indent/#sql-88c_d9:
foreign key (`project_id`) references project(`project_id`):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

@bmused

Comment: @user1142502, looks like you have your answer :)

Comment: I understand that it shows the reason for the error. But I don't understand where I'd go wrong. As the the `referencing` and the `referenced` datatypes are same. It still shows me the same error.
@bmused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

So try:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           `project_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           `project_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           `cons_bal` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
           `non_cons_bal` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
           `budget_head` varchar(100) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
           KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8   


CREATE TABLE `project_map` (                                                                                                                                                                                        
               `id` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                            
               `project_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                
               `head` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                          
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                               
               KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)                                                                                                                                                                                   
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

ALTER TABLE `project_map` ADD CONSTRAINT 
`p_map_fk001` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
REFERENCES project(`project_id`);
```